# Binary File interpretation

Tags: c++, binary

I am reading in a binary file (in c++). And the header is something like this (printed in hexadecimal)

> 43 27 41 1A  00 00 00 00  23 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  04 63 68 72  31 FFFFFFB4 01 00  00 04 63 68  72 32 FFFFFFEE FFFFFFB7

when printed out using:

```
std::cout << hex << (int)mem[c];
```

Is there an efficient way to store `23` which is the `9th` byte(?) into an integer without using `stringstream`? Or is `stringstream` the best way?

Something like

```
int n= mem[8]
```

I want to store `23` in `n` not `35`.

Comment: What do you want to store when the value is `1A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to treat the value as binary-coded decimal? In that case, you could convert it using something like:

```
unsigned char bcd = mem[8];
unsigned char ones = bcd % 16;
unsigned char tens = bcd / 16;

if (ones > 9 || tens > 9) {
    // handle error
}

int n = 10*tens + ones;
```

Answer (score 5):

You did store 23 in `n`. You only see `35` because you are outputting it with a routine that  converts it to decimal for display. If you could look at the binary data inside the computer, you would see that it is in fact a hex 23.

You will get the same result as if you did:

```
 int n=0x23;
```

(What you might think you want is impossible. What number should be stored in `n` for `1E`? The only corresponding number is 31, which is what you are getting.)

Comment: If you could look at the binary data, you would see that it is in fact `0000 0000 0010 0011` (or `0011 0010 0000 0000`, or 64-bit equivalents, or etc). It's been converted just as much to display it in hex as it would be to display it in decimal. I always find pointing this out helps people to comprehend that there is no inherent base (other than binary) in an integer variable.

Comment: I actually had that in a draft of my answer, but couldn't find a way to make it comprehensible. But you are quite right, and that is an important point.

Comment: I understand this but I actually want to use the number 23 later on in code. So how can for example loop 23 times and not 35 times (which is the number I get).

Comment: @Robert: then you should have been clearer in your question and definitively in your title.  What has "Binary file interpretation" to do with using bcd coded bytes?  (well, luckily there are some mindreaders on SO)

Comment: @Robert: How many times would you want to loop if the number is `1E`? You can get what you want with `(n/16)*16+(n%16)`